# MPEG-2 vs AVC vs HEVC Inputs

Tags: rtmp, mpeg2-ts, hevc

I am trying to work with Media live and I'm supposed to send RTMP stream from my iOS/Android devices.
I was checking the pricing model of Media live and I can see there're multiple kinds of input. As I am new to all this (media stuff), I am not sure what they are.

If I send RTMP stream from my iOS device, what kind of input will it be?

1. MPEG-2 Inputs
2. AVC Inputs
3. HEVC Inputs

Comment: The only codec in your list supported by RTMP is AVC. A

Answer (score 2):

These are video compression standards you have listed from the oldest (MPEG-2 in 90') to the newest (HEVC in 2013). 
They have different features and specificiations. Most importantly, the bitrate they output in the same quality level is significantly different. HEVC is the best in terms of bitrate saving, also the most complex in terms of HW/SW.

Comment: makes sense. but about rtmp, which one it supports?

Comment: @Fayza IMHO, RTMP protocol supports only AVC(h264) packed in FLV (Flash Video) container.